# How do I get the div tags to expand to fit the content in my example?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to build a small single web page and am having trouble getting the layout to behave as I would like it to. I'm using `div` tags for the layout.

The problem is that I can't get certain divs to expand their height based on other elements. I've read about various possible solutions but I've tried several and they don't appear to be working for me so I must be implementing them incorrectly. The `clear: both` attribute seems to be the preferred solution but I've tried putting that in various places and it didn't change anything in my result.

In order to simplify the situation for myself I created a separate file just to test this behavior as working in my original file is not working out as long as I don't understand how this works. In the example below I have intentionally given the various divs some random colors in order to illustrate the situation.

[image: layout with div tags in random ugly colors]

```css
.margin {
  background-color: white;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 5vw;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="black">
  <div id="mainBox" style="width: 90vw; margin: auto; height: 300px">
    <div class="margin left" style="background-color: aqua"></div>
    <div id="centerColumn" style="width: 80vw; float: left; background-color: yellow; height: 100%">
      <div class="margin top" style="background-color: lightcoral"></div>
      <div id="mainContentBox" style="width: 100%; height: 300px"></div>
      <div class="margin bottom" style="background-color: hotpink"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="margin right" style="background-color: blue"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The blue columns at the left and right are supposed to extend all the way down to the bottom of the pink bar. So far I've understood that because the height of these columns is set to 100% and the columns are inside the "mainBox" div which is currently set to a fixed height of 300px the columns are also 300px in height. But the `mainContentBox` is also nested within the `mainBox` div and is also currently set to 300px in height.

When I remove the height attribute from "mainBox", I would expect it to stretch in order to be able to fit the content. But what happens instead is that the columns on the left and right disappear altogether, probably because they no longer have a height. Also the yellow part suddenly extends to the top of the bottom pink bar. So it looks as follows.

[image: layout with div tags in random ugly colors]

I'm hoping someone could give me an explanation, not just of how to fix it but also of what I'm doing wrong or where the errors in my thinking lie. Thanks in advance for your time and consideration!

Comment: Just use flex and it will allow you to grow your content section automatically - see my answer in the first duplicate.  The second duplicate is an explanation of why your height percentage doesn't work - if you remove the height, then the percentage doesn't know what to be a percentage of

Comment: Here is an example fiddle of how flex would make your layout quite simple to do: https://jsfiddle.net/7uzowq3t/1/